# Open iTunes Store from iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, url-scheme

I have an app that plays music and I need to implement iTunes search. So, for example, I need to find song by Pink Floyd called Time. How can I open iTunes Store on iOS with results of search query "Pink Floyd - Time"? 
I know it's possible, since there is an app in App Store, called VK App, a client for social network that does exactly that.

And do I need to somehow request approval of this function by Apple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For loading dynamically you can use like this example, it will open the itunes store with the searched item: @"itms://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/advancedSearchResults?artistTerm=pink%20floyd&songTerm=High%20Hopes"

Also, you can perform a search and parse the result (a json) to provide a more specific link using this web service:

https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=pink+floyd%20high%20hopes

Here is the link for the API: http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

I am using the second approach on one of my app's. Works good

Wish it helps

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a link maker designed to do just that.

Here's the **[link to it](https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/us/)**.

Comment: The problem is I need to do that dynamically. And don't those links open iTunes in browser instead of iTunes app?

Comment: I'm not sure about how you'd go about doing it dynamically. Those links will open iTunes/App Store/iBooks as appropriate if you open them on an iOS device.